# Ubuntu 22.04 docker failure in name resolution after moving homes

Tags: networking, server, netplan, hostname

after moving homes i can't connect to the internet (local and outside) my ubuntu server with docker and home assistant installed. I didn't change anything inside the server, just was offline for like 2 months. Now i have the network installed in my new home and when i conected the server name resolution fails.

Some things you may ask for:

- ping google.com

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

- ping 8.8.8.8

```
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

- netplan was working

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    all:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      match:
        name: 'en*'
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.145/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
  version: 2
```

- /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .
```

- Docker is not duplicated

```
dpkg -l | grep docker
ii docker-buildx-plugin 0.10.4-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy amd64
ii docker-ce 5:23.0.5-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy amd64
ii docker-ce-cli 5:23.0.5-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy amd64
ii docker-ce-rootless.extras 5:23.0.5-1~ubuntu.11.04~jammy amd64
ii docker-compose-plugin 2.17.3-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy amd64

snap list | grep docker
No results.
```

- ip interfaces

```
ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_code1 state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 78:2b:cb:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
altname enp0s25
inet 192.168.1.145/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eno1
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::7a2b:cbff:fead:16c9/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mut 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eno1
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::42:3fff:fe06:7d5b/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br-8b3ff1e2bfb1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
link/ether 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope globar  br-8b3ff1e2bfb1
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 xxxx::xx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: veth01ve2d5@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-8b3ff1e2bfb1 state UP group default
link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx link netnsid 0
inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8:vethbe49496@if7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-8b3ff1e2bfb1 state UP group default
link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx link netnsid 2
inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: veth1bc4892@if9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-8b3ff1e2bfb1 state UP group default
link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx link netnsid 1
inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

- ip route

```
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
172.18.0.0/16 dev br8b3ff1e2bfb1 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.145
```

- ufw status

```
Status: inactive
```

- iptables -S

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

- iptables-legacy -S

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

If any more info is needed ask for it please. Thank you so much

Comment: Changed the bios battery and it started working normally again. I leave this here so anyone can test this too. Thanks.